# Reading till a specific point from text file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code for user login, but the problem is I don't know how to read a file in Java. I have a text file which contains usernames and passwords written like;
admin:password
well I need to take username "admin" to check with my first JTextField and password "password" to check with my second JTextField. This action will be performed when I click the login button. As these are the core's of my code.

```
JTextField UserName = new JTextField("Enter Your UserName");
JTextField Password = new JTextField("Enter Your Password");
JButton Login = new JButton ("Login");
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a file line by line this way:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // process the line.
}
br.close();
```

---

But the complete answer to your question is :

```
public class Main {//change it as you wish
    final static String file = "Your file path";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JTextField UserName = new JTextField("Enter Your UserName");
        final JTextField Password = new JTextField("Enter Your Password");
        JButton Login = new JButton ("Login"); 


        Login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String uName = UserName.getText();
                String pass = Password.getText();
                checkUserPass(uName, pass);//check them as you want

            }
        });
    }
    static boolean checkUserPass(String uName, String pass) {
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;

            // I assume your file contains just a line like      username:password
            if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // process the line.


                String[] tmp = line.split(":");
                if (tmp[0].equals(uName) && tmp[1].equals(pass)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: How can i read it till ":" to get the first word as username and after ":" to get the second word as password

Comment: just check it with an if